# Operation timed out SSH to GitHub

Tags: ssh, git

I'm trying to organise my `~/.ssh/` folder, so I've created `~/.ssh/git/id_rsa` and `~/.ssh/git/id_rsa.pub` for my GitHub account. I've also created a config file, as below:

```
Host github.com
        User git
        Hostname github.com
        PreferredAuthentications publickey
        IdentityFile ~/.ssh/git/id_rsa
```

However, whenever I do `ssh -T git@github.com` I'm constantly getting the below error:

```
ssh: connect to host github.com port 1019: Operation timed out
```

My router has that port forwarded. My .ssh directory is also permission 700. What am I missing?

Comment: Do you mean a `config` file as in `.ssh/config` ? I don't recall `ssh` looking for a `.config` file anywhere.

Comment: It is optional.

Comment: Where did you put that file? And are you sure it is processed? You should try with `ssh -F path_to_your/.config -T git@github.com`

Comment: BTW the `ssh` man page doesn't mention `.config` *at all*

Comment: This is one of many articles that discuss a config file in ~/.ssh/: http://nerderati.com/2011/03/simplify-your-life-with-an-ssh-config-file/. In addition to this, I'm able to connect to my server using the config file that directs the ssh daemon to the correct IdentityFile, as that is also in a different directory.

Comment: Anthon, your 'ssh -F ~/.ssh/config -T git@github.com' worked. What can I do now, knowing this?

Comment: Why port 1019?? SSH uses port 22 by default and so does github. If you have some weird firewall rule or something like that that changes the outgoing port then there is no wonder you are having trouble.

Comment: Why not port 1019? Port is clearly not the issue here as I have just made successful connection, read the above comment. Also, /.ssh/config is mentioned in the manual, read description under option -F.

Comment: I'm pretty disappointed by the comments to this question. Whilst your insight is appreciated, both have proven to be derived from ill-informed knowledge, except Anthon pointing out -F.

Comment: amefm I owe you an apology. It is the port. My understanding was that the exiting port would not be identical to the receiving port. Never mind. Useful insight none the less.

Answer (score 1):

Your configuration is not read, as `.config` (in any directory) is not a configuration file that your ssh client normally reads.

You can specify any config file using the `-F` option:

```
ssh -f path_to_your/.config <rest of the options>
```

But for a more permanent solution you should put the configuration data in `~/.ssh/config` as specified in the man page. I have looked, but I don't think you can specify a different location in the `/etc/ssh/ssh_config` for this.

As always, make sure the access to the configuration files (and `~/.ssh` is restricted). `ssh` will normally complain and refuse to operate if access to the configuration, the directory and particularly your private and public keys is not restrictive enough.

Comment: My configuration is in the ssh directory.

Comment: Also, it's config not .config

Comment: it should be in `~/.ssh` not in `ssh`

Comment: Lol read original post. It is. I'm posting from my mobile. Also see my last comment on my question. It was actually the port. I didn't know the config file cremated aliases. Just to point out your original error... Config files are mentioned in the manual under the F option.